# could not find a registered machine named "2014_smart_tv_Emulator_5_1"

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, samsung-mobile-sdk

- I am new in Samsung sdk.
- Download sdk for the Samsung SDK.
- install virtual box and also add vbox for the emulator.
- Emulator is running fine but its not connected run project.

Comment: please put more description and if possible share some screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You need to close virtualBox and then try to launch your application from eclipse.
check Window>Preferences>SamsungSmartTv>Emulator and be sure about all the fields.